# Getting detailed information about an infected website

Tags: network, malware, known-vulnerabilities

I have a set of bad URL's. I want to know the nature of infections affecting these URL's . Running an online scanner such as VirusTotal gives me some basic information from various engines about the URL in question like which engines tag a URL as bad, but the question of 'why' seems a bit unclear from these results.
Is the URL involved in spreading a known malware ? If yes, what malware is it? And how does it affect the end client who visits such a URL? These are some of the questions I'm trying to get answers to. 
Are there resources / methods to get to know such additional information? 
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Hmm, setup a Vmware, install NoScript extenstion, and visit those websites and see exactly where it came from. (It just blocks every "script" to load until you allow it. if it's not a 0-day exploit you must be allowing something to run... like Java or something alose [this/those](http://www.infosecstuff.com/how-hackers-use-javascript-to-distribute-malware/) lines...

Answer (score 1):

I have previously found [wepawet](http://wepawet.iseclab.org/) and [urlquery](http://urlquery.net/) useful in the past. Both service analyze the website in question and give you some good detail about its features and behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Anubis](http://anubis.iseclab.org/index.php?action=home)
It provides a neat report showing all the activities of the Internet Explorer process when visiting this URL.